# Linux mintupdate constantly failing with error

Tags: linux, linux-mint, upgrade

Every time that I try to install updates in mintupdate, I get the following popup.  Does anybody know what could be the cause for this?  I noticed that it mentions *gzip: stdout: No space left on device* so I checked my ssd, however I still have almost 100GB of free space if that has any relation.
[image]

After removing several older kernels and installing a new one then rebooting, I was greeted by this scary looking screen:
[picture taken of monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmoJL.jpg)

Comment: The error message hints that you have run out of space in a ramfs (memory-filesystem).

Comment: Not really Thomas. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are having is because you have run out of space in the /boot partition to create an initrd file (hence the error "no space left in device").

If you have several kernels installed, try to delete alternative kernels before upgrading. However bear in mind it is good practice to have one alternative kernel to boot laying around in case of a bad kernel upgrade.

If you only do have one kernel, you can try, and I have done it more often than I care to admit, to delete the running kernel to install the new one.

Often this situation happens in servers that have been upgraded to new versions several times, as the kernel and associated files used to be smaller. In that case, add this machine to an upgrade list in the short/medium term.

Comment: So you can delete the only kernel without causing issues then?  Just out of curiosity.  It turns out I had many older kernels installed so I had to remove them.  Thanks!

Comment: I have done it multiples times. It works, of course then the installation of a new one has to go through at all costs.

Comment: Okay so now I rebooted and was greeted by this screen (I will update op) it doesn't seem like something that should be related to what I did which seems odd. http://imgur.com/3IAgDGi

Comment: Oh my the joys of a Windows centric world. Have you updated Windows or the BIOS? You have to disable secure Boot in the BIOS. I do not use regular PCs... (only virtual hosts, ARM and OS/X) This is an unrelated issue to this post, if you have trouble with that, I suggest you create a new post.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll mark this question as closed then!